# Read a float from a file on an SD card using Arduino/C++

Tags: c++, c, optimization, arduino

I work with Arduino with Eclipse. I want to read a double from a configuration file. I have made these functions:

```
void Settings::readDouble(char buff, String data, bool flag, double dataToStore) {
    data = "";
    int intPart = 0;
    int probablyFloatPart = 0;

    while(buff != '\n') {
        if(isdigit(buff)) {
            data.concat(buff);
            Serial.println(data);
        }
        else if (buff == '.') {
            char charBuf[data.length()+1];
            data.toCharArray(charBuf,data.length()+1);
            // Convert chars to int
            intPart = atoi(charBuf);
            Serial.println(intPart);
            data="";
            flag = false;
        }
        buff = theSettings.read();
    };

    // Convert string to array of chars
    char charBuf[data.length()+1];
    data.toCharArray(charBuf,data.length()+1);

    // Convert chars to integer
    probablyFloatPart = atoi(charBuf);
    Serial.println(probablyFloatPart);
    if (!flag) {
        dataToStore = intPart + (probablyFloatPart/pow(10, data.length()));
    }
    else {
        dataToStore = probablyFloatPart;
    }
    flag = true;
    //Serial.println(dataToStore, 5);
}
```

From serial.printing I noticed that if the number I want to read has more than four digits on either int or decimal part it gives an error. Basically, I can not tranform a string with more than four bytes to an int. How can I do this?

Comment: what's wrong with `float f; cin >> f;`

Comment: it is for arduino sorry i have not typed it. there is not cin or >>

Comment: Can you show what input you are using, and what the resulting output is?

Comment: reactorGpsX= 4501484 this is one line and the result is.and the result -20500. When the number is 0.35 it works fine.The part that i read the characters is ready and working.

Comment: When i print the String data inside the while loop i see that i fills with the correct number(i get: 4 / 45/ 450/ 4501...) (i do not get  / i get only the number in its loop)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `long` to store values over 32767 (or in an unsigned, over 65535).

I'll be back with a simpler piece of code - I think your code is more complex than it needs to be.

This code uses no standard functions except `isdigit`, and just walks through the number. No limitiation on the size of the number (obviosusly, if you go over the limit for a `double`, then  it will fail). Error handling may need a bit of improvement. I have given it some mild testing...

```
double str_to_double(const char *data, size_t len)
{
    double d = 0.0;
    bool neg = false;
    int index = 0;

    if (data[index] == '-')
    {
    index++;
    neg = true;
    }

    while(data[index] != '.' && index < len)
    {
    if (isdigit(data[index]))
    {
        d = d * 10 + (data[index] - '0');
        index ++;
    }
    else 
    {
        // Handle "bad input" ... 
        return -1;
    }
    }
    if (data[index] == '.')
    {
    index ++;
    double div = 10.0;
    while(index < len)
    {
        if (isdigit(data[index]))
        {
        d += (data[index] - '0') / div;
        div *= 10;
        index++;
        }
        else
        {
        // Handle bad input
        return -1;
        }
    }
    }
    // Flip sign if need be. 
    if (neg)
    {
    d = -d;
    }
    return d;
}
```

Comment: setting intPart as int long  did not change the result tho i was hopping that this could give a correct result.I am waiting for your sample. Or did  you mean that atoi() can not give such a value?

Comment: `atoi` will only return an `int`, I believe. But it's almost as easy to do your own version. Hang on a few more minutes, I'm close...

Comment: well you are correct it runs correctly using atol() but i am waiting to see what you will propose.Probably you will have to suggest something better for the character read (reactGpsX) also but i haven't posted this part of code.

Comment: @kyrpav The above code assumes a string has already been read in (and separated), rather than "reacting to each character" type approach.

Comment: It is pretty long, but upvote b/c it looks like it should work

Comment: I'm sure I could make it shorter by using `data[index++]`, or even a pointer instead of `data[index]`, but I wanted it to be clear and simple as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to save the result in a float. The code below is what I would try.

```
float result = 0;
float scale = 10;
bool pastDecPoint = false;
while(buff != '\n') {
    if(isdigit(buff){
          if(pastDecPoint) 
          {
             result = result + (buff / scale);
             scale = scale * 10;

           }
           else
           {
             result = (result * 10.0) + atoi(buff);
           } 
    } else if (buff == '.') {

        pastDecPoint = true;
    }
    buff = theSettings.read();
};
Serial.println(result);

}
```

I also want to see what petersson comes back with. Which is very similar to Petersson

Comment: but isn't this going to handle only the integer part of the number?If adecimal point appears then for the rest of the line the function will just read the line and will not store anything.

Comment: I added three lines, and now it should handle the floating part of the number